# webapi2 return simple string without quotation mark

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Simple scenario:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok<string>("I am send by HTTP resonse");
}
```

returns:

```
"I am send by HTTP resonse"
```

Just curious, can I avoid the quotation mark in other words return:

```
I am send by HTTP resonse
```

or is this necessary in HTTP?

Comment: How would you expect the calling side to parse this response with quotation marks?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean ... did you mean: How would you expect the calling side to parse this response without quotation marks?

Comment: As it stand the consumer/client has to remove the quotation mark. I just find it a bit redundant but maybe there is a reason for it?

Comment: Lets say I call you and you return a response without " ", just plain text. How am I supposed to parse your response? Where does is end?

Comment: Do you mean the response has double quotes on them?

Comment: In the 'just string content case' I just use: client.Execute(request).Content. Here I know that Content is just ONE string why would I want it to contain quotation marks?

Comment: @Grundy integration tests, fiddler ...???

Comment: so in this case this normal, you can't remove it. Quotation marks in this case not part of string, it just show that you send string

Comment: Sorry but I am trying to establish why this is normal ... I think it has to do with the fact that my default return format is JSON?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can avoid the "

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        public string Get()
        {
            return "qwerty";
        }
}
```

now check `http://localhost:3848/api/values`

and response

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">qwerty</string>
```

The result with `<string>` tag but without quotes :)

**EDIT**

If you don't like this approach,try this.It returns just text

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string result = "Your text";
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: fair enough, however this would not allow me to report errors back as is possible. maybe I should just create a wrapper dto ...

Comment: I tried your first approach and it returned a string with quotes.

Comment: Thanks! We are implementing PayTR payment into our system and callback function was described as "* The RESPONSE that the Callback URL gives to the PayTR system should be plain text OK" 
and We're using ApiControl, and endpoint's return type is IHttpActionResult. 
First we described return type in  IHttpActionResult result, OK("OK") but  got error message saying that response was not actually "OK". 
Apparently, even when you describe your return type as string or IHttpActionResult and return "OK" was not equal to Response.Write("OK").  Content-Length for string "OK" is 4, yours is 2 :)