# Web API 2 return simple string without quotation mark when return type is IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My question is referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688208/webapi2-return-simple-string-without-quotation-mark).

The answer shows only solutions where you would have to change the type of the method to `HttpResponseMessage` or `string`.

This is my method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("I am send by HTTP resonse");
}
```

It returns:

```
"I am send by HTTP resonse"
```

I expect:

```
I am send by HTTP response
```

Is there a way to return a simple string without quotation mark where the return type of the method is `IHttpActionResult`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ApiController.ResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.responsemessage?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

> Creates a [`ResponseMessageResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.responsemessageresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with the specified response.

`ResponseMessageResult` is derived from `IHttpActionResult`

```
public IHttpActionResult Get() {
    var message = "I am send by HTTP response";
    var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(message, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
    };
    return ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Content("I am send by HTTP resonse");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IHttpActionResult is WebApi2 way, you can also use

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "I am send by HTTP response");
}
```

Also if you expect without double quotes please refer to the link you specified in your question.

Comment: so I need to return a `HttpResponseMessage` and can't return a `IHttpActionResult`?

Comment: @SrinivasanJayakumar : So your answer basically is to read another answer which was already linked by the OP and where he obviously didn't find the solution?

Comment: @jps: The other link is having answer to send the response without quotes but this question is specific to return HttpResponseMessage as return type of the function.

Comment: @Nightscape: We can return both but I prefer to use IHttpActionResult as its the recommended. Based on the question I have given the suggestion to return HttpResponseMessage.